# Majorana modes in Kitaev chain

Tags: quantum-field-theory, majorana-fermions, tight-binding

I am reading paper about [Kitaev chain](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440) of electrons, which can exhibit famous Majorana fermions at ends of wire. The Hamiltonian (his Eq. (6)) reads

$H = \frac{i}{2} \sum_j - \mu c_{2j-1}c_{2j} +(w+|\Delta|)c_{2j}c_{2j+1} +(-w+|\Delta|)c_{2j-1}c_{2j+2}$

in terms of the Majorana operators $c_{2j-1}$ and  $c_{2j}$. The symbols $\mu, w, |\Delta|$ can be thought of as parameters controlling Fermi level, hopping and gap.

Kitaev shows there are solutions of Hamiltonian $H$ with zero-energy. He  gives the operators associated to zero-energy solutions in ansatz form (his Eq. (14)):

$b' = \sum_j \left( \alpha_{+}' x_{+}^{j} + \alpha_{-}' x_{-}^{j}\right) c_{2j-1}$

$b'' = \sum_j \left( \alpha_{+}'' x_{+}^{-j} + \alpha_{-}'' x_{-}^{-j}\right) c_{2j}$

where all $\alpha$ are constants and $x_{\pm}$ are unknowns to be found.

Q1) How to find $x_{\pm}$?

Q2) How to show $x_{\pm} = \frac{-\mu \pm \sqrt{\mu^2 - 4 w^2 + 4 |\Delta|^2}}{2 (w+|\Delta|)}$?

I attempted to show it by computing $[b', H]=[b'', H]=0$, but it did not give correct answer.

Any help appreciated.

(Full disclosure: this is reworded version of [closed question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232086/edge-states-of-kitaev-chain))

Comment: Please don't post reworded questions, just edit the old one.

Comment: Hi  @Kyle Kanos Please may you help me? I asked original question on Jan 27 at 14:29. It was closed as unclear on Jan 29 at 23:20. I edited for clarity on  Jan 30 at 15:45, messaging all who closed it. It was not opened and message was not responded too. I edited for further clarity again on Feb 8 at 15:49, messaging all who closed it. It was not opened and message was not responded too. Now it is end of March so I gave up hope those who closed question would let reworded question open. I took drastic step to repost.

Comment: Hi  @FraSchelle I try to explain situation in above comment

Comment: Hi  @John Rennie I try to explain situation in above comment. Notably I myself already put "(Full disclosure: this is reworded version of closed question)" in above post

Comment: Hi @ACuriousMind I try to explain situation in above comments

Comment: Hi @CuriousOne Please see above comments

Comment: After the first edit of your original question it was reviewed with 3/4 reviewers voting to leave it closed. Subsequent edits do not trigger further review, but do bump the question to the top of the active queue. I think you can assume that people saw it. Your original has had only one re-open vote in it's history and that aged away. I doubt you are going to get a favorable effect from repeatedly bugging uses about this.

Comment: @dmckee Thank you for your response. Are you privy as to why the question is still thought unclear after the edit? It seems to me all symbols are defined and perfectly reasonable equations are given. Does the lack of communication from the moderators who closed the question  mean the moderators decided this question is somehow so unclear no amount of future editing would ever render it comprehensible to anyone on this site? It does not seem plausible.

Comment: @Nigel1 If you're not clear about why your original question was closed, I suggest asking for an explanation on [meta].

Comment: @David Z Thank you. I took your advise and posted on Meta  http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/how-to-get-moderators-to-explain-why-question-is-unclear . So far, my troubles have take 2 months. I hope in another 2 months I will finally be able to ask my question...